# Can I enable / Disable an Azure Service Bus Topic using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azureservicebus

I have spent a couple of hours search for a solution to disable my Azure Service Bus Topics using Powershell.

The background for this is we want to force a manual failover to our other region.

Obviously I could click in the Portal:
[image]
but I want to have a script to do this.

Here is my current attempt:
[image]

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're sure your $topic contains the full description, modify the status parameter in the array and then splat it back using the UpdateTopic method. I'm afraid I can't test this at present.

```
$topic.Status = "Disabled"
$topicdesc = $NamespaceManager.UpdateTopic($topic)
```

I don't think you'll need to set the entity type for the Status, nor do you require semi-colons after each line of code in your loop.

**References**

PowerShell Service Bus creation sample script (which this appears to be based off): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2014/12/02/how-to-create-service-bus-queues-topics-and-subscriptions-using-a-powershell-script/

UpdateTopic method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.updatetopic.aspx

Additional note: please don't screenshot the code - paste it in. I'd rather copy-and-paste than type things out.

Comment: thanks for the message. I will try this now. Regarding pasting code, it never formats correctly. I even tried to use a 3rd party code formatting tool within Blogger but it never worked. Can you pint me to a solution where I can paste code and it works?

ps. when I paste it, it pastes the first few lines then I have to go and edit it for 15 minutes to make it look right. Russ

Comment: Use a decent text editor - Notepad++ is readily available - to edit your script. Remove any blank lines in your code. Ensure no line is longer than 80 chars. Then select the entire script and press "tab" to insert 4 spaces at the beginning of each line (assuming the text editor is set to replace tabs with 4 spaces).

Comment: ...and then paste the result into the edit box here. Works fine for me - doesn't take a minute.

Comment: Thanks that's great. And the topics stuff you gene me worked perfectly